The closedness in Banach Space Decomposition

Exercise: Suppose that $E$ is a Banach space and $E=L\oplus M$, where $L$ is a closed subspace and $M$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $E$. Prove that $T(E)$ is closed $\Longleftrightarrow$ $T(L)$ is closed.

There exists a finite-dimensional subspace $M_1\subset M$, s.t.
$$T(E)=T(L)+T(M)=T(L)\oplus T(M_1).$$
To prove "$\Longrightarrow$", we define the following map
$$\widetilde{T}:L/ker(T|_L)\oplus T(M_1)\rightarrow T(L)\oplus T(M_1)=T(L)+T(M)=T(E)$$
by
$\widetilde{T}[(x+ker(T|_L))\oplus y]=Tx+y$, where $x\in L$ and $y\in T(M_1)$. It can be verified that the continous map $\widetilde{T}$ is injective and has closed range. Then it is bounded below. Hence one can verify $T(L)=\widetilde{T}[(x+ker(T|_L))\oplus\{0\}]$ is closed. This idea relies on the following classical result from Fredholm theory.

Suppose $X$ is Banach space and $Y$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $X$. If $T(X)+Y$ is closed for some $T\in B(X)$, then $T(X)$ is closed. In particular, if codim$T(X)<\infty$, then $T(X)$ is closed.

My question: Is there an elementary proof of "$\Longrightarrow$", which does not rely on isomorphism relations：
$$X/ker(T)\cong T(X).$$
In other words, can we directly use the definition of closed set to verify the conclusion?

It suffices to restrict to one dimensional $M,$ and proceed by induction with respect to the dimension. Should be easier

@Ryszard Szwarc I am sorry. How to use the assumption $M$ is one dimensional?

Let $f_1,f_2\,\ldots, f_n$ form a basis of $M.$ Denote $M_k={\rm span}\{f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_k\}$ and $E_k=L\oplus M_k,$ $E_0=L.$ It suffices to show that $T(E_{k-1})$ is closed iff $T(E_k)$ is closed for $1\le k\le n.$ This would imply that $T(L)=T(E_0)$ is closed iff $T(E)=T(E_n)=T(L\oplus M)=$ is closed.
In this way we have reduced the problem to the case $\dim M=1.$
Concerning $"\Longleftarrow" ,$ assume $T(L)$ is closed and $\dim M=1.$ There are two cases
$$ T(L\oplus M)=T(L),\quad T(L\oplus M)=T(L)\oplus T(M),\ \dim T(M)=1$$
We need to analyze the second case. Denote $V:=T(L)$ and $W:=T(M).$ We want to show that $V\oplus W$ is closed. First we show that there is a constant $c>0$ such that $$ \|v+w\|\ge c\|w\|,\quad v\in V,\ w\in W\quad (*)$$
If there is no such constant there exist $v_m\neq 0$ and $w_m\neq 0,$ such that $$ \|v_m+w_m\|\le {1\over m}\|w_m\|\quad (**)$$ WLOG we may assume that $\|w_m\|=1.$ Thus there is a convergent subsequence $w_{m_l}.$ Let $\displaystyle\lim_lw_{m_l}=w.$ Then $\|w\|=1.$ By $(**)$ we get that the sequence $v_{m_l}$ is convergent, say to $v,$ and $v=-w\neq 0.$ This leads to a contradiction as $V\cap W=\{0\}.$ Thus $(*)$ holds.
Assume that $v_m+w_m\to y.$ By $(*)$ we get that the sequence $w_m$ is convergent as
$$\|(w_m+v_m)-(w_{m'}+v_{m'}\|\ge \|w_m-w_{m'}\|$$ Thus $v_m$ is convergent as well. Denote $w=\lim w_m$ and $v=\lim v_m.$ Then $v\in V,$ as $V$ is closed by assumption, and $y=v+w\in V\oplus W.$ Hence the closedness of $V\oplus W=T(L)\oplus T(M)$ is proved.

Why the $\widetilde{T}(\widetilde{L})=T(L)$? I think if $\widetilde{L}={x+kerT~|~x\in L}$, then $\widetilde{T}(\widetilde{L})=T(L)$.

@Insomnia You have answered your question.

But why does ${x+kerT~|~x\in L}=L/(L\cap ker T)$ hold？

You are right. The last part was incorrect. I have removed it.

Thank you for your answer.
